# Supersonic - How to post an image gotten from the phone's camera in a multipart post

Tags: android, angularjs, hybrid-mobile-app, steroids

Ok, here's the rundown of the problem:

I'm using AppGyver steroids and supersonic in combination with AngularJS to develop an Android hybrid app that targets the API that I cannot influence on (it cannot be changed to allow for my problems to be resolved).

Appgyver Supersonic provides a method for taking a picture with your phone's camera and provides two options for a result after you have taken the picture - you can either get the file url of the picture taken or you can get the picture as a dataUrl.

I have to target API with a post request that has this file in it's form data. As a solution I have tried loading the response string into blob object (by intermediate conversion to byte array) and the posting all of that, like so:

```
var options = {
    allowEdit: true,
    targetWidth: 300,
    targetHeight: 300,
    destinationType: "dataURL",
};

supersonic.media.camera.takePicture(options).then(function (result) {
    var imageGotten = result;

    var bytes = new Int16Array(imageGotten.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < imageGotten.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = imageGotten.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    var imageToPost = new Blob([bytes], { type: "image/jpeg" });

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', imageToPost);

    $http({
        url: "API_method_that_is_being_targeted",
        method: "POST",
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
        data: formData
    })
    .success(function (result) {
        //further logic
    });

});
```

This works properly in the sense that it posts the data and it gets success result from the server. The problem is, that when I get the data from the server, the image I receive cannot be displayed due to it's corruption. The admins of the API assure me that this would be resolved if I could post a File object instead of the Blob object which I do now. But the File object, as far as I can tell from researching the subject a bit (could be wrong of course), cannot be directly instantiated in javascript but only gotten from a file input field, and Blob object is something that inherits from File, and therefore it should not matter if I post one or the other.

Is there something I'm missing, and if so, what do you suggest as a solution to this problem. Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: did you ever resolve? trying to do something similar, not quite at the point where its working or not though, but unclear why you were getting corruption

Comment: ok yep, mine are corrupted too, please tell me you resolved this :D

Comment: I did resolve it, but by changes made to API eventually. They agreed to add a method that accepts dataURIs which they decode and save as image directly on their side.

Comment: yeah I was thinking I was going to do the same, I control the API anyways so all good. cheers for the response, glad you got it sorted :)